# Lifetime may not live long enough, where to put the lifetime annotation?

Tags: string, rust, lifetime

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone, Copy, Serialize)]
pub struct Unit<'a> {
    id: &'a str,
}

impl Unit<'_> {
    fn unpack<'a>(bytes: &'a [u8]) -> Option<Self> {
        match from_utf8(bytes) {
            Ok(v) => Some(Self { id: v }),
            Err(_) => None,
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is right on this line `Some(Self { id: v })` with the value of `v` with the error: "lifetime may not live long enough, this usage requires that `'a` must outlive `'1`".

Where do I put the lifetime annotation to tell the compiler that `v` should have the lifetime value of `'a`?

Comment: Do you mean `Option<Unit<'a>>`? Here `Self` is `Unit<'_>` which isn't going to match.

Comment: @tadman good catch, didn't even see that error because it was hidden by the previous error. Will update my question.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is the `impl Unit<'_>`, looks like this makes the `Self` type be `Unit<'1>`. If you specify the impl to be for `Unit<'a>` like so, the lifetime relationship is ok:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Unit<'a> {
    id: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Unit<'a> {
    fn unpack(bytes: &'a [u8]) -> Option<Self> {
        match core::str::from_utf8(bytes) {
            Ok(v) => Some(Self { id: v }),
            Err(_) => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to fix the problem at the call site, for this to by adding the `'a` to `unpack(bytes: &[u8])` making it `unpack(bytes: &'a [u8])`. This makes sure that the entire lifetime of bytes is shared between all of it's dependent data.

```rust
pub struct TAIP<'a> {
    /// [char; 1]
    pub qualifer: Qualifer,
    /// [char; 2]
    pub message: Message,
    pub data: Data,
    /// This is referred to as ID in the spec.
    pub unit: Option<Unit<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> TAIP<'a> {
    fn unpack(bytes: &'a [u8]) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        let pv = PV::unpack(&bytes[4..34]);

        Ok(Self {
            qualifer: Qualifer::from_u8(bytes[1] as char),
            message: Message::unpack(&bytes[2..4]),
            data: Data::PV(pv),
            unit: Unit::unpack(&bytes[38..42]),
        })
    }
}
```